# Bulk Insertion in Sequelize hasMany() Association

Tags: node.js, model, sequelize.js, associations

First of all let me explain what I want to do. I have two model `User` and `Product` well define. I use method created by sequelize when defining association with `hasMany()` and `belongsTo()` to create my product.

`user.hasMany(Product)
 Product.belongsTo(User)`

and I used this method to create the `product` from `user`.

```
User.findOne({where:{id:SomeID}}).then((userObj)=>{
 userObj.createProduct(productobj).then((userObj)=>{

             //product  creation handling

 }).catch((errorProduct)=>{

             //product  creation error handling
 });

       }).catch((error)=>{

         //user creation error handling
});
```

My **productobj** is an array of json object that belongs to `User`.
It works fine when it's only one product but it failed when there is more than one product. So I wonder if there is any method that I can use to bulk create those products from the same user.
I may be doing it the wrong way. So if there is a better way then I will highly appreciate it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The association `user.hasMany(Product)` will add below methods to `User` model.

````js
/**
 * The addAssociations mixin applied to models with hasMany.
 * An example of usage is as follows:
 *
 * ```js
 *
 * User.hasMany(Role);
 *
 * interface UserInstance extends Sequelize.Instance<UserInstance, UserAttributes>, UserAttributes {
 *  // getRoles...
 *  // setRoles...
 *  addRoles: Sequelize.HasManyAddAssociationsMixin<RoleInstance, RoleId>;
 *  // addRole...
 *  // createRole...
 *  // removeRole...
 *  // removeRoles...
 *  // hasRole...
 *  // hasRoles...
 *  // countRoles...
 * }
 * ```
 *
 * @see https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/has-many.js~HasMany.html
 * @see Instance
 */
````

For your case, you should use `userModel.addProducts(productModels)`. E.g.

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { Model, DataTypes, HasManyAddAssociationsMixin } from 'sequelize';

class User extends Model {
  public addProducts!: HasManyAddAssociationsMixin<Product, number>;
}
User.init(
  {
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
    },
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'users' },
);

class Product extends Model {}
Product.init(
  {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'products' },
);

User.hasMany(Product);
Product.belongsTo(User);

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    // seed
    await User.create(
      {
        email: 'example@gmail.com',
        products: [{ name: 'apple' }, { name: 'amd' }],
      },
      { include: [Product] },
    );
    // add another two products for this user
    const SomeID = 1;
    const productobj = [{ name: 'nvidia' }, { name: 'intel' }];
    const productModels = await Product.bulkCreate(productobj);
    const userObj = await User.findOne({ where: { id: SomeID } });
    await userObj.addProducts(productModels);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

data row in the database:

```sh
=# select * from users;
 id |       email
----+-------------------
  1 | example@gmail.com
(1 row)

node-sequelize-examples=# select * from products;
 id |  name  | userId
----+--------+--------
  1 | apple  |      1
  2 | amd    |      1
  3 | nvidia |      1
  4 | intel  |      1
(4 rows)
```

NOTE: These methods only accept target model(s) as their parameter, **NOT** a plain javascript object or array of objects. You need to `bulkCreate` the products. Then, use `userModel.addProducts(productModels)` to associate these products to this user

Comment: `Product.bulkCreate()` will usually fail here: the products cannot ever be created without a parent user, even as an intermediary step. The database doesn't know you're about to add them to a user. Creating a userless product would violate a `notNull` constraint on the `userId` column

Answer (score 1):

It seems [this is not supported](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3277) as yet (although requested since 2015). We have a few options to workaround:

1. If your model definitions allow it, you can do as with slideshowp2's answer: bulkCreate the products, and then assign them to the user. This won't work if you are allowing nulls on the `customerId` column (which is probably not a good idea).
2. If you know the userId, you can include this id in each product item to be created, then use Products.bulkCreate(). This will work.
3. Create every product individually against the user. There's various ways of doing this eg something like

   Promise.all(
   productArray.map((prod) => {
   return user.createProduct(prod)
   }))